# Past tense of "dare" auxiliary verb

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, auxiliary-verbs

**Dare** as an auxiliary verb is used as:

> I **dare** threaten her.

How to change it into the **past tense?**

Thank you.

Comment: Kumar it might be helpful if you explained why what you found when you looked for the past tense of dare in the dictionary didn’t help you.

Comment: Virolino's answer is a good one, but I just wanted to point out that you haven't used ***dare*** as an auxiliary verb here. It's a lexical verb, but *catenative* - that is, it takes a non-finite verb phrase as its argument. Auxiliary *dare* is only used in negative and interrogative forms. Just because a verb appears in front of another verb doesn't mean that it's an auxiliary.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dare):

> Etymology 1 (verb)
>
> dare (third-person singular simple present dare or dares, present participle daring, **simple past *dared* or (archaic) *durst***, past participle dared)

and

> Etymology 2 (verb)
>
> dare (third-person singular simple present dares, present participle daring, **simple past and past participle *dared***)

Example (thanks go to @JasonBassford)

> I **dare** (to) threaten her → I **dared** (to) threaten her.

Comment: +1 Although I would provide an actual example. *I **dare** (to) threaten her* → *I **dared** (to) threaten her.*

Comment: @JasonBassford Your examples are of lexical "dare", not modal auxiliary "dare", which is what the OP asked about.

Comment: @BilJ: That is exactly the example of the OP. Can you please explain what is the difference between lexical and modal in this context? How can we decide if it is one or the other?

Comment: The OP's example uses lexical date (as a catenative), I suspect the OP is just confused by the difference between catenative and auxiliary verbs.

Comment: @SamBC: It is possible, I thought of that too. But I am not an "expert" to the level to make a statement regarding that. I asked for some reference just because my findings and some of the claims seemed to contradict each other.

Comment: @SamBC  Yes, but In the simple construction both aux "dare" and lexical "dare" are catenatives, at least they are in the framework I follow.

Comment: @BillJ: Ah, the taxonomy I'm familiar with differentiates between catenatives and auxiliaries. However, every authority I've found says the OP's example cannot be auxiliary.

Comment: @SamBC I agree. Aux "dare" only occurs in non-affirmative contexts, unlike the OP's example. And lexical "dare" normally requires _do_- support. The problem arises with examples like "He dared not obstruct them", which has primary verb negation, so that lexical "dare" would require _do_-support, as in "He didn't dare obstruct them". In such examples, it seems impossible to tell whether "dare" is lexical or auxiliary.

Answer (score -1):

> - *I dare threaten her.*

The modal auxiliary "dare" doesn't have a past tense, and it only occurs in non-affirmative contexts, e.g. "I daren't tell anyone"; "Dare they accept her challenge?"

Your example is not non-affirmative, and hence is ungrammatical, but *I daren't threaten her* / *Dare I threaten her?* would be OK.

In order to express past time, you need to use lexical "dare", where the auxiliary "do", (or the perfect) carries the tense:

*I didn't dare to tell anyone.*

*Do they dare to accept her challenge?*

*She had dared to contradict him.*

Comment: @BillJ: Can you please provide a reference to support your claim, that "dare" does not have a past tense?

Comment: @virolino I said that **modal auxiliary** "dare" does not have a past tense.